# What is the difference between Dim s As String and Dim s As [String]?

Tags: vb.net, string, declaration

What is the difference between:

```
Dim s As String
```

and

```
Dim s As [String]
```

Comment: Okay, I just have to say it...please please please do NOT name a variable [If], [As], [Dim], etc!  Just because you can, really doesn't mean that you should.  I'm not saying you were going to do that, but just thought it needed to be written down somewhere.

Comment: @Matt: No sane person would name a variable `[If]`.  `[New]` is more likely, though.

Comment: New.  Ugh.  It's like in C#.  I personally think case-sensitivity is a very bad thing.  I tell all my junior developers that if they ever name a variable objectId, and have another one named objectID, and mean something different, then I'm going to cut off their internet access.

Comment: By the way, in C#, you can (but **must not**) write `object @if;`.

Comment: @Matt - this language feature makes automated code generation a *whole* lot easier.  I agree that no one should ever need to do this in their own code.

Comment: +1 for @Michael Petrotta, it really does help with code generation. [Class] is the one I usually run into the most, someone made a column in the database with that name because it made the most sense and now we're stuck with it.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference.

In VB, you can wrap an identifier in brackets to force it to be parsed as an identifier and not a keyword.

For example, you can write

```
Dim [If], [As], [Dim]
```

without any syntax errors.

The brackets have no effect other than indicating that the identifier isn't a keyword, so `someVar` and `[someVar]` are identical.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same exact thing.  When you put brackets around the type name it doesn't do anything different but when the brackets are placed around an identifier it allows you to use a reserved keyword.

So this would be legal:

```
Dim [String] as String
```

because the brackets around the identifier name allow the compiler to know you meant to use a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 2):

There's no functional difference in the code posted.

You can use square brackets to declare a variable with the same name as a VB.NET keyword.  Given a variable named "Loop" (a reserved keyword in VB):

```
Loop.Visible   = True  ' Causes an error.
[Loop].Visible = True  ' Sets the Visible property of the variable named "Loop".
```

This example is from [MSDN's page on the topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwx24eb6%28vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Technically there is no difference. `Dim s As String` is same as `Dim s As [String]`